# Send data between two components in Angular CLI: 11.2.7

Tags: angular

I have a following token-model.ts:

```
export class TokenModel {
    authToken: AuthToken;
    email;
    refreshToken: RefreshToken;
}

class AuthToken {
    stringToken
    username
    validTo;
}

class RefreshToken {
    stringToken
    username;
}
```

And a following tokenService.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { TokenModel } from '../models/token-model';


@Injectable()
export class TokenService {
    private tokenData = new ReplaySubject<TokenModel>(1);
    token = this.tokenData.asObservable();

    constructor(){}

    setTokenData(data){
        this.tokenData.next(data);
    }

    getTokenData(){
        return this.token;
    }
}
```

In my **login component** i receive the token data and set it into token model with:

```
this.tokenService.setTokenData(data as TokenModel);
```

And i believe the data is set correctly, because it can be found somewhere deep when i do       `console.log(this.tokenService.getTokenData());`

With this i set the data "globally" and after setting it i want to use it in other component called **datepick component**.

The main things to set to getting the data from the "global state service" are:

1. importing stuff that is needed like subscribtion from rxjs, token service and token model etc..
2. define subscription: Subscription;
3. token: TokenModel;
4. defining tokenService: TokenService in constructor
5. and subscribing in the function where ill need the stuff from tokenService(auth token string from tokenModel) with:     `this.subscription = this.tokenService.token.subscribe((token: TokenModel) => { this.token = token; });`

But when i `console.log(this.token);`, it says undefined.

And as i said before, when i `console.log(this.tokenService.getTokenData());` and go deep into the Observer structure, i find the data that was set into the observer.

What am i doing wrong that i get undefined when i call the data in the other component?

P.S. i did a lite version on this and just set some string data in a simple message service, and its still not working, so nothing is wrong with the tokenmodel or something.

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. The other component where you want to use the data and where you set the data are they "under" the same module ? Maybe your TokenService is not a singleton and you accidently create more of them.

Comment: They are under the same module(theres only one), how would i make it a singleton? Doesnt the (1) in service make it a singleton?

Comment: `Doesnt the (1) in service make it a singleton?`

 Nope, with that you are only telling to ReplaySubject to remember the last 1 value , and if someone will subscribe to it the replay subject can send the last '1' value in the beginning. 

You create a singleton service if you register them in a root module level. You can achive this if you put them into root modules provider array , or if you declare providedIn: 'root' in the Injectable annotation 

`@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root',
})`

Comment: @MátéPankucsi i annotated tokenService.ts with > @Injectable({  providedIn: 'root', }) and i added it to app.module.ts into providers  > providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }, TokenService] , it is still saying undefined

Comment: @MátéPankucsi and when i  console.log(this.tokenService.getTokenData()); in the datepick compmonent it doesnt say undefined, but it is rather empty. I can conclude  from this that the data is still not being set as a singleton.

Comment: your code seems to work as expected here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eukomg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: @Stavm bunch of errors when i copy your code from stackblitz... private tokenData = new BehaviorSubject<TokenModel>({}); this doesnt work. also where are the declarations of exports etc? Why is hello component declared in appmodule ts?

Comment: Can you share the code with us ? It would be easier to solve your problem.  Maybe you call console.log faster then your setToken method. If you annotated properly I can guarantee it will be a singleton service. And FYI the whole service instance will be a singleton not only the tokenData variable.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in my mistake, whereby i was defining provider TokenService in app.modules.ts instead of app.components.ts, so the service was never enabled to serve as a provider between components.